# Linking canvas to bitmap

Tags: android, canvas

I am drawing on canvas which is linked to bitmap as follows:-

```
         bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);

         canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

where bitmap and canvas are global variables.

Now I want the RGB value of the pixel shown at the touched co-ordinates. 
My code:--

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    Log.d("touch", "onTouchEvent: " + event.getX() + "," + event.getY() );
    int pixel,x = 0,y=0;
    pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);    <------Point of Interest (POI)
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
    Log.d("touch", "redvalueIs"+redValue);
    Log.d("touch", "bluevalueIs"+blueValue);
    Log.d("touch", "gvalueIs"+greenValue);
 }
```

Now my drawing is quite colorful with shapes in different colors but when I click black,red,green or any other color shapes all I am getting is all the three values zero.

I think its maybe I should link canvas instead of bitmap at POI but don't know how. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
x = 0,y=0;
```

you are never getting the value of that pixel.
change it to:

```
x =event.getX();
y = event.getY();
```

before doing this:

```
pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

or you will always get the pixel in the position `0,0`